# problems with scroll and position

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm trying to do a page that's divided in two big divs that contains information.

One of this divs is the actual page (width:910px), and the other is a pane that is positioned FIXED in the html and is (width:400px).

So the second div is over the first.

The thing is that i'm trying to put overflow auto in the two divs and the two scrolls appears at the right of the navegator, and I need that the scroll of the first div could appear in the left of the second div (the one thats positioned fixed and is over the first div).

this is my code:

body
div id="user_id"
(full of code with the page content)
/div

div id="pane"(the content of div pane)
/div

then the css:

id pane { background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #282829; bottom: 0; position: fixed; right: 0; top: 0; width: 450px; font-family: HelveticaNeue; font-size: 14px; overflow: auto;}

id user_id {width: 910px; float: left; margin-top: 80px; margin-left: 10px; position: fixed; overflow: auto;  }

like this i get the two scrols but the two of them are at the right of the browser. I need that the id_user can have the scroll at the side of pane and floating with it

anyone knows how can i do this??? thanks!

Comment: share some code please (and CSS)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to fix the width of the other `div` too? For example:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

And then in your CSS:

```
div#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
    div#container div#div1 {
        width: 560px;
        float: left;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    div#container div#div2 {
        width: 400px;
        float: left;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

Comment: I can't do that couse the div 1 has 910px full of things, this page is made like if it were only the div 1, and you have an option that make appear the div two with some options to interact by ajax with div 1. so it has to have 910px beacuse it has all the information there...but i want that when you are with the two divs you can see them all with the scrolss

Comment: You can't move the scroll bar position, since it's rendered by the browser (well, you can make the scroll appear on the left but that wouldn't solve your problem). It sounds like you want to be using iframes?

Comment: yeah...i want to avoid the use of iframes. I thought maybe can be a way that when the scroll is needed and you are with the mouse inside the div 2, it can move down and up but you don't see the actual scroll bar you know?

Comment: You would essentially need two `div` elements, one which acts as a mask and the other which is 100% height. You could then adjust the margin of the inner `div` when the user scrolls.

Comment: thanks ben! i finally made it with position fixed right:400px in the user_id div..thanks for your help!